# Understanding some cc1 parameters

Tags: c, assembly, gcc

Running `$ gcc -v` results in the first command being a `cc1` command. First of all, where can I find what all the parameters mean? I tried typing in `man cc1`, `help cc1`, etc. and couldn't find anything.

On linux, `gcc -v file.c` results in the first command being (reorganized a bit):

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/cc1 \
    file.c \
    -o ccN7P5D111.s
    -quiet \
    -v \
    -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu \
    -quiet \
    -dumpbase file.c \
    -mtune=generic \
    -march=x86-64 \
    -auxbase file \
    -version \
    -fstack-protector \
    -Wformat \
    -Wformat-security \
```

- `file.c` is the file to compile.
- `-o ccN7P5D111.s` is the outfile (almost a random tmpfile)

And the others, well, not too sure. What would be a basic description of them? Which of them are important?

Comment: At least some of those are also `gcc` options, and it seems reasonable to think that they would mean the same thing to `cc1` as to `gcc`.  But I'm not quite seeing the point of the question, because `cc1` is an internal component of GCC, not a user-facing executable.

Comment: Have you tried reading [the GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.2.0/gcc/)? As mentioned, some of these are also `gcc` frontend options. It's possible that the internal `cc1` parameters are also documented.

Comment: `cc1` is an implementation detail of gcc and thus only marginally documented.  You are not supposed to invoke it directly as a user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not in the `$PATH`, that's why `gcc -v` runs it via a full path.  It doesn't have a man page because it's not intended to be invoked manually, just via the `gcc` front-end.

**NONE OF THEM ARE IMPORTANT, if you're not (trying to be) a GCC developer don't run it manually.**  If you are, then read the source code.

On my system, `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.1.0/cc1 --help` prints a bunch of help, like most programs do.

```
The following options are specific to just the language Ada:
  -fdump-scos                           [available in Ada]

The following options are specific to just the language AdaSCIL:
 None found.  Use --help=AdaSCIL to show *all* the options supported by the AdaSCIL front-end.

The following options are specific to just the language AdaWhy:
 None found.  Use --help=AdaWhy to show *all* the options supported by the AdaWhy front-end.

The following options are specific to just the language BRIG:
  -fassume-phsa                         [available in BRIG]

The following options are specific to just the language C:
  -fgimple                              [disabled]

The following options are specific to just the language C++:
  -Wplacement-new                       -Wplacement-new=1
  -Wplacement-new=<0,2>                 [available in C++]

The following options are specific to just the language D:
  -Hd <dir>                             
  -Hf <file>                            
  -Wcast-result                         [available in D]
  -Wspeculative                         [disabled]
  -X                                    [disabled]
  -Xf <file>                            
  -fall-instantiations                  [disabled]
  -fassert                              [available in D]
  -fbounds-check                        [available in D]
  -fbounds-check=[on|safeonly|off]      [available in D]
  -fdebug                               [disabled]
...

The following options control parameters:
  --param=align-loop-iterations=        4
  --param=align-threshold=<1,65536>             100
  --param=analyzer-bb-explosion-factor=         5
  --param=analyzer-max-enodes-per-program-point=        8
  --param=analyzer-max-recursion-depth=         2
  --param=analyzer-min-snodes-for-call-summary=         10
  --param=asan-globals=<0,1>            1
...

The following options control compiler warning messages:
  -W                                    -Wextra
  -Waggregate-return                    [disabled]
  -Waggressive-loop-optimizations       [enabled]
  -Wanalyzer-double-fclose              [enabled]
  -Wanalyzer-double-free                [enabled]
  -Wanalyzer-exposure-through-output-file       [enabled]
```

GCC does have a gcc-internals manual, which includes documentation for [`collect2`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Collect2.html) which you'd asked about in an earlier question.

The gccint manual is *not* just how to use the parts, though.  It also documents machine-description files and stuff like that which tell GCC about the instructions an ISA has.  And stuff you'd need to know if you wanted to modify the C code of GCC's own source code, e.g. to add new optimizer passes, or understand GIMPLE and RTL.

I didn't actually find a description of `cc1` options in the gccint manual.  In the regular (for end-users) GCC manual, there's an [Invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html#Invoking-GCC) entry, but of course that's for the front-end, not for `cc1`.

Full-text searching in the `info` pages locally didn't find documentation of that, so the `--help` output is probably the best you'll get.